# Possible to share Mac OS Desktop using Parallels and LiveMeeting

Tags: mac, parallels

Is it possible to share your Mac OS Desktop using LiveMeeting and Parallels?

I've tried the following:
1) Startup Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard
2) Startup Win 7 VM in Parallels 4 
3) Connect to a LiveMeeting using the LiveMeeting Desktop option
4) Switch Parallels into Coherence mode
5) Share my desktop in the LiveMeeting console

This just shares the Win 7 desktop.  Is there any config changes that will allow me to share my Mac desktop and/or Mac Apps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Mac is the host, you should use a Mac tool to share the desktop. That way the virtualized Windows 7 will also be shared.

To turn on the Mac screen sharing set the appropriate settings in the System Preferences.

If you need to share with many platforms have a look at the various different [third-party VNC applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).